# Group of order $143$, counting argument.

Tags: group-theory

I am  trying the following exercise (I cannot use Cauchy's theorem, it's not in my course yet) :

> Let $G$ be a group of order $143=11\times13$, prove that that $G$ contains an element of order $13$

If $G$ is cyclic, then I know that there exist a unique subgroup of order $d$
where $d$ is a unique positive divisor of $143$.
If $G$ is not cyclic, then I don't know how can I conclude without Cauchy's theorem, perhaps by counting the element of $G$ ?

If $G$ does not contain an element of order $13$, then let $t$ be the order of $g$. By Lagrange's theorem every element of $G$ must have order $13$ or $11$, since the groupe is not trivial, there exist an element of order $11$.
The order of $g^k$ is $11/(k,11).$

Therefore, $g^{13}$ as order $11$ and $g^i$ as order $11$, for any $1\le i\le11.$ How can I continue or proceed ? Thanks

Comment: If there is no element of order $13$, then all non-indentity elements have order $11$, so the whole group is a union of cyclic subgroups of order $11$, any two of which intersect only in the identity element. So, if there are $k$ such subgroups, then the total number of elements is $10k+1$, which cannot be equal to $143$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I got it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no element of order 13, then for all g in G, g non identity, |g| = 11 or 143, but if there exists p in g: |p|=143, |p^11| = 13, contrary to our assumption. If, however all non-identity elements of G are of order 11, there are 142 such elements. However, there is a property that in a finite group, the number of elements of order d is a multiple of phi(d), and since phi(11) =10, 10|142 which is a contradiction, so there must exist an element in G of order 13.